# Azure DevOps single pipeline for multiple projects without multiple azure-pipelines.yml files

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

We have an Azure DevOps Pipeline defined as a template in a `.yml` file, and would like to use this to build 100+ projects.
There is zero parameterization to do, and the template essentially just runs against the project repo as-is.

Normally, we would just go into each of those project repos and create an `azure-pipelines.yml` file and reference the template pipeline, easy.

However, I would like to know if we can avoid creating these `azure-pipelines.yml` in each of the 100+ project repos. Is there some way to just run the template against 100+ repos, but as separate pipelines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

YAML pipelines are based upon the YAML being stored *in the application's repo*, as code, alongside the application code. You can pull in *templates* from other repos, but you can't have one pipeline that is automatically valid for any repo.

Trying to use one template to build 100+ applications without the possibility of pinning the template to a specific version on an application by application basis is setting yourself up for a nightmare at some point in the future, when the template changes in such a way that it's no longer valid for a subset of your 100 applications.